# Regex to pull out postal code from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a search string that a user inputs text into.

If it contains any part of a postal code like:  1N1 or 1N11N1 or 1N1 1N1 then I want to pull that out of the text.

example:

```
John Doe 1n11n1
```

or

```
1n1 John Doe
```

or

```
John 1n11n1 Doe
```

I want to capture this:

```
postal_code: 1n11n1
other: John Doe
```

Can this be done using regex?

Comment: I don't get the `1N1` metaphor.

Answer (score 4):

Try matching the regular expression `/((?:\d[A-Za-z]\d)+)/` and returning `$1`:

```
def get_postal_code(s)
  r = /((?:\d[A-Za-z]\d)+)/
  return (s =~ r) ? [$1, s.sub(r,'')] : nil
end

# Example usage...
get_postal_code('John Doe 1n11n1') # => ['1n11n1', 'John Doe ']
get_postal_code('1n1 John Doe') # => ['1n1', ' John Doe']
get_postal_code('John Doe 1n1') # => ['1n1', 'John Doe ']
```

You could also cleanup the "other" string as follows.

```
  ...
  return (s =~ r) ? [$1, s.sub(r,'').gsub(/\s+/,' ').strip] : nil
end
get_postal_code('John Doe 1n11n1') # => ['1n11n1', 'John Doe']
get_postal_code('1n1 John Doe') # => ['1n1', 'John Doe']
get_postal_code('John Doe 1n1') # => ['1n1', 'John Doe']
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what is the format of the postal codes where you are, but I'd definitely resort to regexlib:
http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=postal%20code

You'll find many regular expressions that you can use to match the postal code in your string.
To get the rest of the string, you can simply do a regex remove on the postal code and get the resulting string. There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but I'm going for simplicity :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done using a regex. Depending on the type of data in the rows you may be at risk for false positives, because anything that matches the pattern will be seen as a postal code (in your example though that does not seem likely).

Assuming that in your patterns N is an alpha character and 1 a numeric character you'd do something like the below:

```
strings = ["John Doe 1n11n1", "1n1 John Doe", "John 1n1 1n1 Doe"]
regex = /([0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}\s[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9]{1}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9]{1})/
strings.each do |s|
  if regex.match(s)
    puts "postal_code: #{regex.match(s)[1]}"
    puts "rest: #{s.gsub(regex, "")}"
    puts
  end
end
```

This outputs:

```
postal_code: 1n11n1
rest: John Doe 

postal_code: 1n1
rest:  John Doe

postal_code: 1n1 1n1
rest: John  Doe
```

If you want to get rid of excess spaces you can use String#squeeze(" ") to make it so :)